# Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core, attributerouting, asp.net-core-1.0

Do I need to configure anything to use attribute routing in an ASP.NET Core 1.0 application?

The following doesn't seem to be working for me. I was expecting to hit this method when I go to localhost:132/accounts/welcome

```
public class AccountsController : Controller
{

   [Route("welcome")]
   public IActionResult DoSomething()
   {
       return View();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative you can use is to apply a `RoutePrefix` or `Route` on your class. Then you won't have to repeat that part on the action attributes.

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
   [Route("welcome")]
   public IActionResult DoSomething()
   {
       return View();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I needed to add the controller token in there

```
public class AccountsController : Controller
{

   [Route("[controller]/welcome")]
   public IActionResult DoSomething()
   {
       return View();
   }

}
```